# Highcharts pie chart issue (gaps between pie slices)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a half-donut pie chart using a 100-point series in Highcharts. Please see screenshot.

[image: screenshot of pie chart]

I've spent the last four or five hours trying to figure out why there's a line between each pie slice. It's not a border, because if I change the background color behind the chart to black, I can actually see the black between each pie piece. So there's a 1-pixel gap between each pie piece. I would like the chart just to be a solid color, not have a 1-pixel gap between each pie piece. Pulling my hair out trying to figure out where this setting is. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: set series.borderWidth to 0.  If that isn't the problem, include a fiddle or some code.  https://jsfiddle.net/f64cr667/

Comment: Thanks, I was able to fix it by adjusting borderWidth, but it's not exactly as you thought. See my answer to myself below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fix the issue by reading about series.borderWidth. (Thanks to @BarbaraLaird.) This is from the Highcharts API docs:

> borderWidth: Number The width of the border surrounding each slice.
>
> When setting the border width to 0, there may be small gaps between
>   the slices due to SVG antialiasing artefacts. To work around this,
>   keep the border width at 0.5 or 1, but set the borderColor to null
>   instead.
>
> Defaults to 1.

I was able to fix the issue by setting borderWidth to 1 and setting borderColor to null. (My borderWidth was previously set to 0 and borderColor was undefined.) That filled in the "gaps" between the antialised slices.